# Making Eclipse give bottom space without manual carriage returns

Tags: eclipse

I'm using Eclipse for coding. I hate that I have to enter a lot of Carriage Returns (enters) at the bottom of the page to move the code up so I can have more space for reading. I hate that because it adds the empty lines to my text source files. Is there a way to let Eclipse give me more bottom space?

Comment: Could you show a screen dump of what you mean?

Comment: Why can't you user Page UP and Page DOWN keys?